# pexpect : Sending Function characters

Tags: python, pexpect

Hi everyone.I need to send F2 key using pexpect.I have tried child.send("^[OQ").But it is not working.The sendcontrol() function can send only control characters ,so I have no idea.Anybody please suggest a way to send F2 key

Answer (score 0):

Run the [getch.py](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/blob/master/tests/getch.py) script from the pexpect test directory to see what raw bytes the terminal is getting, and press F2. Then you'll need to press Ctrl+Space to quit.

On my system, F2 gives me the numbers 27, 79, 81. So the equivalent with pexpect should be:

```
p.send(b'\x1bOQ')
```

Or:

```
p.sendcontrol('[')
p.send('OQ')
```

Comment: Even in my system I got 27, 79, 81.I tried both the things which you suggested,but it is not working.

Comment: What program are you sending the F2 to? What does it do when it receives it, and what is it doing when you send that sequence under pexpect?

Comment: I am sending F2 to the device which is connected using serial cable using plink command.

Comment: Does the device manual say what bytes it expects? Possibly the terminal is changing them somehow before they get sent to the device.